# Windows Azure - Installing MSI causes hangup?

Tags: asp.net, powershell, azure

I have a Windows Azure startup task that I am trying to run for installing an MSI. I am trying to run the task via a powershell script. I can confirm that the powershell script runs when I have the following:

```
"Before powershell" >> C:\hello.txt

$msi = "E:\approot\bin\StartupScripts\AppInitalization_x64.msi"

if($true -eq [System.IO.File]::Exists($msi))
{
   "file exists" >> C:\hello.txt
}
else
{
  "file does not exist" >> C:\hello.txt
}

"After powershell" >> C:\hello.txt
```

If I run a deployment, my `hello.txt` contains "Before, file exists" and "after".

However if I try to change the file exists condition to be:

```
  $arguments= ' /qn /l*v C:\AppInitalization_x64.txt' 
  Start-Process `
     -file  $msi `
     -arg $arguments `
     -passthru
```

The deployment hangs (i've let it wait up to five hours).
If I remote into the machine and try that same powershell snippet, it installs just fine.

Any ideas on why it would be hanging when I have this as part of the startup script?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at `AppInitialization_x64.txt` to see where the Windows Installer package is hanging? That should give you a good indication, since you've already enabled verbose logging.

Comment: AppInitialization_x64.txt does not get created. Also there is no indication in the event log that the setup has started.

Comment: I presume you're looking at the Application event log, where Windows Installer messages would get logged? Hmmm. Can you log which user account the task is getting executed as? eg. `Out-File user.txt -In $env:username`